# String as a member of Union

Tags: structure, unions

I was going through this code to find what the answer could be. As far as I know in unions memory address of each member is the same. In the below code if there was a character instead of string, that would be  easy. But now I am confused.... How the value of `i=259`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   union cq1
   {
        int i;
        char ch[2];
   };
   union cq1 u1;
   u1.ch[0]=3;
   u1.ch[1]=1;
   printf("%d %d %d", u1.ch[0], u1.ch[1], u1.i);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A character array such as `char ch[2]` is an array of 2 `char`s, each 1 byte long. This means that in memory, it is a `char` and then a second `char`.

This union contains 2 types, a 32-bit (on my machine) integer, and an array of 2 chars. 
Since the largest type is 32-bits, or 4 bytes, the total size of the union is 4 bytes. You can verify this with `printf("%d\r\n", sizeof(u1));`

`ui1.ch[0] = 3` sets the first byte to 3, and `u1.ch[1] = 1` sets the second byte to 1. When I view this in a debugger, I see `0x60fefc: 03 01 00 00`. That is to say, there are the bytes 3, 1, 0 and 0, at the memory location corresponding to `u1`. `u1.i` interprets this as a 4-byte integer in Least Significant Byte (LSB) order. A 4-byte integer in LSB format is represented in memory in the format `A B C D`, where the value is `A + 256*B + 65536*C + 16777216*D` (for positive values up to 2,147,483,647). So, `03 01 00 00` is `3 + 256*1`, which equals 259.

Comment: **A + 256*B + 65536*C + 16777216*D**, I did not get that .And if I had 'char ch[3] ' and I assign 'u1.ch[2]=1' will the value of 'i' be 3+256*1+65536*1=65795 ?

Comment: @Bruce Yes, exactly.